# Wordpress Widget Slider is causing a lot of white space

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a template on Wordpress and it is loading

originally it will load like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBb1P.png

But then after that it will load in the images and that will create a large white space in between the divs, see in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Fpb.png

This seems to be from the section-id: colormag_featured_posts_slider_widget-3

The website's URL is: https://www.oddsonfpl.com/

I have regenerated the image so that the thumbnail would be smaller, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be only at the first loop. Cant say if it's a bug or wrong configuration . You can try to set `adaptiveHeight: true` to `adaptiveHeight: false` in your theme javascript setting file (`wp-content/themes/colormag/js/colormag-slider-setting.js`) and add this to your CSS file:

`.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
    height: 350px !important;
}`

Comment: Thank you so much, that has worked a charm Jose! Really appreciate your help